# Android Maven pom version code upate?

Tags: java, android, maven

I'm using Maven to build my Android application and everything has been working great for the past 6 months or so. Now that I am iterating on releases and updating the app more frequently I would like the apk that is created to use the Android manifest app version for its name.

Is there any way to do something like this in the pom where {android-manifest-version} is the version set in the manifest:

```
<version>{android-manifest-version}-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: The apk that Maven generates uses the <version> tag to name the apk

Comment: Property substitution is not allowed in the `version`. It is allowed in `finalName`, which I assume is being used to create the file name.